# renaming a directory and its subdirs without affecting their files

Tags: linux, shell-script, rename, perl

I have to rename directories under the root directory with prefix "ms_PF" and then rename their subdirectories with the modified name of the main directory with an extra "_", and then copy all directories and their subs to root as follows:

```
root
   maindir1
   maindir2
           subdir1
           subdir2
           subdir3
```

maindir1 and maindir2 to be renamed with prefix "ms_PF_" and copied direct to root, because maindir2 has subdirectories they will carry the new name of maindir2 which is ms_PF_maindir2 plus and underscor (_) then all subs will be copied to root as follows:

```
ms_PF_maindir1
ms_PF_maindir2_subdir1
ms_PF_maindir2_subdir2
ms_PF_maindir2_subdir3
```

Assistance in this matter is highly appreciated. 
My attempted solution is something like this, but it actually needs fixing:

```
root_dir="/dwn/icbu_dwn/LL"
prefix="ms_PF_"
do_it () {
awk '{ print "mv $root_dir $prefix ${root_dir/\//_}" }' | sh
}
find "$root_dir" -depth -type d | do_it
```

Comment: [Also posted on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279054/renaming-a-directory-and-its-subdirs-without-affecting-their-files). [Please don't post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073)

Comment: The `${root_dir/\//_}` substitution requires bash/zsh/ksh -- probably won't work with plain sh.

Comment: Thanks Glenn for your comment, and my apologies for posting the same question on another Stack Exchange site as my intention was to resolve a pressing issue that was unwillingly accepted. Is there another method or version of ${root_dir/\//_} that would work with plain sh? Your input is really precious to me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only a few directories, do it by hand (anything else will be more work in writing/debugging than in doing).

If it is a largeish set, use `find(1)` to create a list of the affected files, and use your favorite editor to transform that into a script doing the moving. Check it for mistakes, and fire away.

If even larger/repetitive, I'd do essentially the same as the above, but do the "edit the path into the new name" by `sed(1)` on-the-fly. Perhaps even called directly from `find`. Would make a nice one-liner to scare newbies witless...

Answer (score 1):

This will do the renaming in the right order. Note the trailing slash in the first pattern limits the matches to directories.

```sh
cd root
for dir in maindir*/*/ maindir*; do
    echo mv $dir ms_PF_${dir/\//_}
done
```

outputs

```
mv maindir2/subdir1/ ms_PF_maindir2_subdir1/
mv maindir2/subdir2/ ms_PF_maindir2_subdir2/
mv maindir2/subdir3/ ms_PF_maindir2_subdir3/
mv maindir1 ms_PF_maindir1
mv maindir2 ms_PF_maindir2
```

Comment: Thank you Glenn for your promptness and sincere help. In fact, I ran your script as it is with modifying root and maindir values, but got "${root/...}: Bad substitution". Any suggestions?

Comment: Please put your code up in the question so you can format it properly

Comment: Sorry Glenn for the mess I made in your solution. However, I put my attempted script up in the question as you asked; hope it makes sense in concept, but it does need to be looked into. I do appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: @terry If you're satisfied with glenn's script, remove the `echo` to actually perform the moves.

Comment: Thanks Gilles, I've actually done so getting the same msg: ${dir/...}: Bad substitution. Due to having to do this task, I've been reading a lot as my main expertise is in mobile tech! So any assistance is highly appreciated.